# Trying to change pitch of audio file with scikits.samplerate.resample results in garbage audio from pygame

Tags: python, scipy, pygame, audio-processing

My problem is related to pitch-shifting audio in Python. I have the current modules installed: numpy, scipy, pygame, and the scikits "samplerate" api.

My goal is to take a stereo file and play it back at a different pitch in as few steps as possible. Currently, I load the file into an array using `pygame.sndarray`, then apply a samplerate conversion using `scikits.samplerate.resample`, then convert the output back to a sound object for playback using pygame.

The problem is garbage audio comes out of my speakers. Surely I'm missing a few steps (in addition to not knowing anything about math and audio).

```
import time, numpy, pygame.mixer, pygame.sndarray
from scikits.samplerate import resample

pygame.mixer.init(44100,-16,2,4096)

# choose a file and make a sound object
sound_file = "tone.wav"
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_file)

# load the sound into an array
snd_array = pygame.sndarray.array(sound)

# resample. args: (target array, ratio, mode), outputs ratio * target array.
# this outputs a bunch of garbage and I don't know why.
snd_resample = resample(snd_array, 1.5, "sinc_fastest")

# take the resampled array, make it an object and stop playing after 2 seconds.
snd_out = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(snd_resample)
snd_out.play()
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that pygame works with `numpy.int16` arrays but the call to `resample` return a `numpy.float32` array:

```
>>> snd_array.dtype
dtype('int16')
>>> snd_resample.dtype
dtype('float32')
```

You can convert `resample` result to `numpy.int16` using `astype`:

```
>>> snd_resample = resample(snd_array, 1.5, "sinc_fastest").astype(snd_array.dtype)
```

With this modification, your python script plays the `tone.wav` file nicely, at a lower pitch and a lower speed.

Comment: Oh man, I don't know how to thank you. No wait, I do, I can send you beer money through PayPal if you would accept my offer. I've countless hours looking for a solution. This is fantastic.

Comment: Glad to see you like my response :) You don't have to offer me anything, your question was interesting and I also have learned a few things with it!

Comment: Would it be possible to save the modified pygame.micer.Sound object as a sound file instead of playing it?

Comment: I would do it with the SciPy io.wavefile module:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/io.html

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably using python audiere.

Here is a link, I used it to do the same sort of thing, it's very easy, just read all the documentation.

http://audiere.sourceforge.net/home.php

Comment: Thanks, Audiere was my first choice, but I couldn't get it to _make_ without errors. I'm not too bright with this stuff so I kind of have to go with what work given my limited skills.

Comment: This looks good, does it work for python 2.7? It seems to be for python 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the scikits.samplerate.resample is "thinking" your audio is in another format than 16bit stereo. Check the documentation on scikits.samplerate on where to select the proper audio format in your array - 
If it resampled 16 bit audio treating it as 8 bit garbage is what would come out.

Answer (score 0):

From the `scikits.samplerate.resample` documentation:

*If input has rank 1, than all data are used, and are assumed to be from a mono signal. If rank is 2, the number columns will be assumed to be the number of channels.*

So I think what you need to do is something like this to pass the stereo data to `resample` in the format it expects:

```
snd_array = snd_array.reshape((-1,2))

snd_resample = resample(snd_array, 1.5, "sinc_fastest")

snd_resample = snd_resample.reshape(-1) # Flatten it out again
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, but the same output comes out.